# Recursion problem on Codewars Kata - Snail Trail

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Very new to coding so please bear with me. I am attempting to solve this Kata on Codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/snail/train/javascript

Basically given an array like

```
[ 
    [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [12,13,14,5], 
    [11,16,15,6], 
    [10,9, 8, 7]
];
```

It would return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`.

A snail trail spiraling around the outside of the matrix and inwards.

I am just solving for the case where the matrix is n x n where n is > 1 and an even number for now.

I got it working by declaring outputarray outside the function but I want that array to be declared within the function, hence the inclusion of this line: `var outputarray = outputarray || [];`

Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
snail = function(array) {
  if (array.length == 0) {
    return outputarray
  }
  var n = array[0].length - 1;
  var outputarray = outputarray || [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    outputarray.push(array[0].splice(0, 1));
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    outputarray.push(array[i].splice(n, 1));
  }
  for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    outputarray.push(array[n].splice(i, 1));
  }
  for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    outputarray.push(array[i].splice(0, 1));
  }
  array.pop();
  array.shift();
  snail(array);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/e3skjtrn/1

Comment: Another [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57946428) & [A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949870) gives some good approaches.  (I like my solutions involving a slice-and-transpose recursion.)  And there are many other approaches in many languages in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726756

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-recursive approach that doesn't mutate the input `array`. It works by keeping track of the top-left coordinate `x, y` and the size `n` of the spiral.

```js
snail = function(array) {
  const { length } = array;
  const result = [];
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  let n = length;

  while (n > 0) {
    // travel right from top-left of spiral
    for (let i = x; i < x + n; ++i) result.push(array[y][i]);

    // shrink spiral and move top of spiral down
    n--; y++;

    // travel down from top-right of spiral
    for (let i = y; i < y + n; ++i) result.push(array[i][x + n]);

    // travel left from bottom-right of spiral
    for (let i = x + n - 1; i >= x; --i) result.push(array[y + n - 1][i]);

    // shrink spiral
    n--;

    // travel up from bottom-left of spiral
    for (let i = y + n - 1; i >= y; --i) result.push(array[i][x]);

    // move left of spiral right
    x++;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(snail([[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define another function inside `snail`, which calls itself recursively, while also defining the `outputarray` inside `snail`. That way, `outputarray` isn't exposed to the outer scope, but the recursive function can still see it.

Also note that `splice` returns an array, so right now, your `outputarray` gets composed of an array of arrays. Spread into `push` instead to fix it, so that the `outputarray` becomes an array of numbers:

```js
const input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10, 9, 8, 7]
];

const snail = (array) => {
  const outputarray = [];
  const iter = () => {
    if (array.length == 0) {
      return
    }
    var n = array[0].length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      outputarray.push(...array[0].splice(0, 1));
    }
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      outputarray.push(...array[i].splice(n, 1));
    }
    for (var i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      outputarray.push(...array[n].splice(i, 1));
    }
    for (var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      outputarray.push(...array[i].splice(0, 1));
    }
    array.pop();
    array.shift();
    iter(array);
  };
  iter(array);
  return outputarray;
}

console.log(snail(input));
```

Comment: This seems like the only answer that actually attempts to answer the OP's question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take some borders for the left, right, upper and lower indices and loop until no more indices are available.

```js
function snail(array) {
    var upper = 0,
        lower = array.length - 1,
        left = 0,
        right = array[0].length - 1,
        i = upper,
        j = left,
        result = [];

    while (true) {
        if (upper++ > lower) break;

        for (; j < right; j++) result.push(array[i][j]);
        if (right-- < left) break;

        for (; i < lower; i++) result.push(array[i][j]);
        if (lower-- < upper) break;

        for (; j > left; j--) result.push(array[i][j]);
        if (left++ > right) break;

        for (; i > upper; i--) result.push(array[i][j]);
    }

    result.push(array[i][j]);
    return result;
}

console.log(...snail([[1, 2, 3, 4], [12, 13, 14, 5], [11, 16, 15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
const input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10, 9, 8, 7]
];

function snail(array) {
  var res = [];
  
  if (!array.length) return res;
  var next = array.shift();
  if (next) res = res.concat(next);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    res.push(array[i].pop());
  }
  next = array.pop()
  if (next) res = res.concat(next.reverse());
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    res.push(array[i].shift());
  }

  return res.concat(snail(array));
}
console.log(snail(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be according to the rules (or spirit?) of the kata, however, you can just glue it all together and sort.

```js
function snail(trail) {
  const numeric = (a, b) => a - b
  const gather = (items, item) => items.push(parseInt(item, 10)) && items
  const inline = (route, points) => points.reduce(gather, route) && route
  const order = paths => paths.reduce(inline, []).sort(numeric)

  return order(trail)
}

const trail = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    [12, 13, 14, 5], 
    [11, 16, 15, 6], 
    [10, 9, 8, 7]
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(snail(trail)))
```

Comment: I think the point was to traverse in a path of a spiral, not return a sorted list of values (e.g., switching 4 and 3 should result in [1, 2, 4, 3...etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents, using the customary recursion:

```js
function f(A){
  return A.length > 1 ? A.splice(0,1)[0].concat(
    f(A[0].map((c, i) => A.map(r => r[i])).reverse())) : A[0]
}

var A = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4], [12,13,14, 5], [11,16,15, 6], [10, 9, 8, 7]]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A)))
```

Comment: It should be noted, though, that this solution mutates the original.  To my mind, that's disqualifying.  (And yes, I know that this is easy to fix.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet mine isn't the only answer here that mutates the original, is it?

Comment: @ScottSauyet this is for demonstration only. I would prefer a more efficient solution in practice without transposition :)

Comment: No, just the first one I read.  And I recall you [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949438/1243641) an earlier version of this question in a non-mutating manner.  And as this is mostly a puzzle, I imagine, and not likely to run out of stack space or other resources, I'd usually prefer the cleanest solution unless it proves impractically slow.

Comment: @ScottSauyet how do you define "clean?"

Comment: @ScottSauyet that earlier answer looks like making the turns was more of a puzzle than the puzzle itself :)

Comment: I don't try to define "clean".  Like [Judge Potter Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobellis_v._Ohio#Supreme_Court) said, I know it when I see it.  I really like code that is simple in the [Rich Hickey](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/) sense.  For instance here, I would prefer to define and use a rotation function and build this atop that, rather than merge its implementation into the function.  (And of course `rotate` can be built atop `transpose` and `reverse`...)

Comment: @ScottSauyet that's fair. And I like to go against the grain. Where someone champions clean I sometimes like to throw in dirty and vice versa.