# how to generate spiral matrix in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to generate sprial matrix in javascript.

question
**Given an integer A, generate a square matrix filled with elements from 1 to A^2 in spiral order.**

**input** : 3

```
 [   [ 1, 2, 3 ],
     [ 8, 9, 4 ],
     [ 7, 6, 5 ]   ]
```

when `input is 4`

```
 [   [1, 2, 3, 4],
     [12, 13, 14, 5],
     [11, 16, 15, 6],
     [10, 9, 8, 7]   ]
```

my approach is to create `2d` array with `0` value and after that they will fill values.

```js
let generateMatrix = function(A) {
  let arr = [], counter = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < A; i++) {
    let items = []
    for (let j = 0; j < A; j++) {
      items.push(0)
    }
    arr.push(items)
  }

  var spiralMatrix = function(arr) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
        arr[0][i] = counter++;
      }
    }
    return arr
  }
  return spiralMatrix(arr)
}
console.log(generateMatrix(2))
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The acclaimed original is about reading a matrix in a spiral fashion. The OP is about creating one

Comment: yes this is not duplicate question

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually read them that quickly.  Reopened.

Comment: There are several possible approaches available here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Spiral_matrix#C.23 (this link points to the javascript solution). Just shift the indexes accordingly to get the desired result.

Comment: Love the question. May I ask what is the use-case?

Comment: Not only is this question a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946428/any-idea-or-solution-to-this-matrix-challenge), it has duplicate answers as well.

Comment: @גלעד ברקן: I think you're missing the fact that this question asks how to wind an array into a matrix, whereas that one asks how to unwind a matrix into an array.  Clearly answers to the two questions may be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take loops for each edges and loop until no more ranges are avaliable.

```js
function spiral(length) {
    var upper = 0,
        lower = length - 1,
        left = 0,
        right = length - 1,
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        result = Array.from({ length }, _ => []),
        value = 1;

    while (true) {
        if (upper++ > lower) break;

        for (; j < right; j++) result[i][j] = value++;
        if (right-- < left) break;

        for (; i < lower; i++) result[i][j] = value++;

        if (lower-- < upper) break;

        for (; j > left; j--) result[i][j] = value++;
        if (left++ > right) break;

        for (; i > upper; i--) result[i][j] = value++;
    }

    result[i][j] = value++;
    return result;
}

var target = document.getElementById('out'),
    i = 10;

while (--i) target.innerHTML += spiral(i).map(a => a.map(v => v.toString().padStart(2)).join(' ')).join('\n') + '\n\n';
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer ..why so loops and whats is role of loops

Answer (score 2):

This is in some ways the reverse of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949870) I gave to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57946428).  We can recursively build this up by slicing out the first row and prepending it to the result of rotating the result of a recursive call on the remaining numbers:

```js
const reverse = a => 
  [...a] .reverse ();

const transpose = m => 
  m [0] .map ((c, i) => m .map (r => r [i]))

const rotate = m => 
  transpose (reverse (m))
  
const makeSpiral = (xs, rows) =>
  xs .length < 2
    ? [[... xs]]
    : [
        xs .slice (0, xs .length / rows),
        ... rotate(makeSpiral (xs .slice (xs .length / rows), xs.length / rows))
      ]

const range = (lo, hi) =>
  [...Array (hi - lo + 1)] .map ((_, i) => lo + i)

const generateMatrix = (n) => 
  makeSpiral (range (1, n * n), n)

console .log (generateMatrix (4))
```

A sharp eye will note that `rotate` is different here from the older question.  `transpose (reverse (m))` returns a clockwise rotated version of the input matrix.  `reverse (transpose (m))` returns a counter-clockwise rotated one.  Similarly, here we rotate the result of the recursive call before including it; whereas in the other question we recurse on the rotated version of the matrix.  Since we're reversing that process, it should be reasonably clear why.

The main function is `makeSpiral`, which takes an array and the number of rows to spiral it into and returns the spiraled matrix.  (If `rows` is not a factor of the length of the array, the behavior might be crazy.)  `generateMatrix` is just a thin wrapper around that to handle your square case by generating the initial array (using `range`) and passing it to `makeSpiral`.

Note how `makeSpiral` works with rectangles other than squares:

```js
makeSpiral ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 2) //=>
// [
//   [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6], 
//   [12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7]
// ]

makeSpiral ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 3) //=>
// [
//   [ 1,  2,  3,  4], 
//   [10, 11, 12,  5], 
//   [ 9,  8,  7,  6]
// ]

makeSpiral ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 4) //=>
// [
//   [ 1,  2,  3], 
//   [10, 11,  4], 
//   [ 9, 12,  5], 
//   [ 8,  7,  6]
// ]

makeSpiral ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 6) //=>
// [
//   [ 1, 2], 
//   [12, 3], 
//   [11, 4], 
//   [10, 5], 
//   [ 9, 6], 
//   [ 8, 7]
// ]
```

The other functions -- `range`, `reverse`, `transpose`, and `rotate` -- are general purpose utility functions for working with arrays or matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code should do what you are trying to.

```
// This is your Editor pane. Write your JavaScript hem and
// use the command line to execute commands
let generateMatrix = function(A) {
  let arr = [],
    counter = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < A; i++) {
    let items = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < A; j++) {
      items.push(0);
    }
    arr.push(items);
  }

  var spiralMatrix = function(arr) {
    let count = 1;
    let k = 0; // starting row
    let m = arr.length; // ending row
    let l = 0; // starting column
    let n = arr[0].length; //ending column

    while (k < m && l < n) {
      // top
      for (var i = l; i < n; i++) {
        arr[k][i] = count;
        count++;
      }
      k++;

      // right
      for (var i = k; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i][n - 1] = count;
        count++;
      }
      n--;

      // bottom
      if (k < m) {
        for (var i = n - 1; i >= l; i--) {
          arr[m - 1][i] = count;
          count++;
        }
        m--;
      }

      // left
      if (l < n) {
        for (var i = m - 1; i >= k; i--) {
          arr[i][l] = count;
          count++;
        }
        l++;
      }
    }
    return arr;
  };
  return spiralMatrix(arr);
};

console.log(generateMatrix(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.

I keep the current "moving direction" in `dx` and `dy`, such that the next matrix element indices are given by `x+dx` and `y+dy`.

If the next item is already filled or is out of bounds, I change this direction clockwise. Otherwise, I fill it with the next value.

```js
const size = 6;
const matrix = Array(size).fill().map(() => Array(size).fill(0));

let x = -1;
let y = 0;
let dx = 1;
let dy = 0;

function changeDirection() {
  if (dx === 1) {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 1;
  } else if (dy === 1) {
    dy = 0;
    dx = -1;
  } else if (dx === -1) {
    dx = 0;
    dy = -1;
  } else {
    dx = 1;
    dy = 0;
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
  const yNext = y + dy;
  const xNext = x + dx;
  const nextRow = matrix[yNext] || [];
  const nextItemContent = nextRow[xNext];
  if (nextItemContent === undefined || nextItemContent > 0) {
    changeDirection();
    i--;
    continue;
  }
  y = yNext;
  x = xNext;
  matrix[y][x] = i + 1;
}

const result = document.getElementById('result');
matrix.forEach(row => {
  row.forEach(value => {
    result.innerHTML += value.toString().padStart(3);
  });
  result.innerHTML += '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm calculating the index, each number should go in a linear array

```js
console.clear();

Array.prototype.range = function(a, b, step) {
    step = !step ? 1 : step;
    b = b / step;
    for(var i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        this.push(i*step);
    }
    return this;
};

const spiral = function(dimen) {
  "use strict";
  const dim = dimen;
  const dimw = dim;
  const dimh = dim;

  var steps = [1, dimh, -1, -dimh];
  var stepIndex = 0;
  var count = 1;
  var countMax = dimw
  var dec = 0
  var index = 0;
  
  var arr = []; 
  arr = arr.range(1, dimh * dimw)
  const newArr = arr.reduce((coll, x, idx) => {
    index += steps[stepIndex]
    coll[index-1] = idx+1;

    if (count === countMax) {count = 0; stepIndex++; dec++;}
    if (dec === 1) {dec = -1; countMax--}
    if (stepIndex == steps.length) {stepIndex = 0}
    
    count++;
                   
    return coll;
  }, []);
  
  var ret = []
  while (newArr.length) {
    ret.push(newArr.splice(0,dimw))
  }
  return ret
}

console.log(spiral(3))
console.log(spiral(4))
console.log(spiral(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n=14; // size of spiral 
var s=[]; // empty instruction string
function emp() {} // no move
function xpp() {xp++;} // go right
function xpm() {xp--;} // go left
function ypp() {yp++;} // go down
function ypm() {yp--;} // go up
var r=[xpp,ypp,xpm,ypm]; // instruction set
s.push(emp); // push 'no move' (used for starting point)
var c=n-1;
while (c-->0) s.push(r[0]); // push first line - uses a different rule
for (var i=1;i<2*n-1;i++) {  // push each leg
    c=Math.floor((2*n-i)/2);
    while (c-->0) s.push(r[i%4]);
}
var sp=new Array(n); // spiral array
for (var i=0;i<n;i++) sp[i]=new Array(n);
var xp=0; // starting position
var yp=0;
for (var i=0;i<n*n;i++) {
    s[i](); // execute next instruction
    sp[yp][xp]=i+1; // update array
}
for (var i=0;i<n;i++) console.log(sp[i].toString()); // log to console
```

This code makes a macro of functions to generate a run sequence, for example:

> 'right4, down4, left4, up3, right3, down2, left2, up1, right1

and then implements it.

Comment: it should be right5 at the start of your description

Comment: @yunzen; the first instruction is 'right4' for n=5. I specify the starting position as (xp,yp)=(0,0) later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to Spiral Matrix from leetcode, maybe this can help

https://leetcode.com/problems/spiral-matrix/

```js
var spiralOrder = function(matrix) {
  if (matrix.length == 0) {
    return [];
  }
  let result = [];
  let rowStart = 0;
  let rowEnd = matrix.length - 1;
  let colStart = 0;
  let colEnd = matrix[0].length - 1;
  while (true) {
    // top
    for (let i = colStart; i <= colEnd; i++) {
      result.push(matrix[rowStart][i]);
    }
      
    rowStart++;
      
    if (rowStart > rowEnd) {
      return result;
    }
      
    // right
    for (let i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++) {
      result.push(matrix[i][colEnd]);
    }
      
    colEnd--;
      
    if (colEnd < colStart) {
      return result;
    }
      
    // bottom
    for (let i = colEnd; i >= colStart; i--) {
      result.push(matrix[rowEnd][i]);
    }
      
    rowEnd--;
      
    if (rowEnd < rowStart) {
      return result;
    }
      
    // left
    for (let i = rowEnd; i >= rowStart; i--) {
      result.push(matrix[i][colStart]);
    }
      
    colStart++;
      
    if (colStart > colEnd) {
      return result;
    }
      
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(
  spiralOrder([[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16]])
);
console.log(spiralOrder([[7], [9], [6]]));
console.log(spiralOrder([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]));
console.log(spiralOrder([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]));
```

Comment: Note that this solves the reverse problem from what is in the question.  The question asks how to wind an array of numbers into a matrix.  This answer show how to unwind a matrix into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer using only one for loop -

```
function matrix(n) {
  const arr = [];
  let row = 0;
  let column = 0;
  let counter = 1;
  let edge = n - 1;

  let leftToRightRow = false;
  let topToBottomCol = false;
  let rightToLeftRow = false;
  let bottomToTopCol = false;

  for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
    if (column <= edge && !leftToRightRow) {
      if (!Array.isArray(arr[row])) {
        arr[row] = []; // if array is not present at this index, then insert one
      }
      arr[row][column] = counter;
      if (column == edge) {
        row = row + 1;
        leftToRightRow = true;
      } else {
        column = column + 1;
      }
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else if (column === edge && !topToBottomCol) {
      if (!Array.isArray(arr[row])) {
        arr[row] = []; // if array is not present at this index, then insert one
      }
      arr[row][column] = counter;
      if (row === edge) {
        column = column - 1;
        topToBottomCol = true;
      } else {
        row = row + 1;
      }
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else if (column >= 0 && !rightToLeftRow) {
      arr[row][column] = counter;
      if (column === 0) {
        row = row - 1;
        rightToLeftRow = true;
      } else {
        column = column - 1;
      }
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else if (row >= n - edge && !bottomToTopCol) {
      arr[row][column] = counter;
      if (row === n - edge) {
        column = column + 1;
        bottomToTopCol = true;
        //setting these to false for next set of iteration
        leftToRightRow = false;
        topToBottomCol = false;
        rightToLeftRow = false;
        edge = edge - 1;
      } else {
        row = row - 1;
      }
      counter = counter + 1;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

****Solution is implemented in C++, but only logic matter then you can do it in any language:****

```
vector<vector<int> > Solution::generateMatrix(int A) {
    vector<vector<int>> result(A,vector<int>(A));
    int xBeg=0,xEnd=A-1;
    int yBeg=0,yEnd=A-1;
    int cur=1;
    while(true){
        for(int i=yBeg;i<=yEnd;i++) 
            result[xBeg][i]=cur++;

        if(++xBeg>xEnd) break;

        for(int i=xBeg;i<=xEnd;i++) 
            result[i][yEnd]=cur++;

        if(--yEnd<yBeg) break;

        for(int i=yEnd;i>=yBeg;i--) 
            result[xEnd][i]=cur++;

        if(--xEnd<xBeg) break;

        for(int i=xEnd;i>=xBeg;i--) 
            result[i][yBeg]=cur++;
            
        if(++yBeg>yEnd) break;
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solition in c#:

For solving this problem we use loops for each moving directions

```
     public IList<int> SpiralOrder(int[][] matrix) {
        var result = new List<int>();
            var n = matrix[0].Length;
            var m = matrix.Length;
            var i = 0;
            var j = 0;
            var x = 0;
            var y = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                //left to right moving:
                while (x <= n - 1 - i)
                {
                    result.Add(matrix[y][x]);
                    x++;
                }
                if (result.Count == n * m)
                    return result;
                x--;y++;

                //up to down moving:
                while (y <= m - 1 - j)
                {
                    result.Add(matrix[y][x]);
                    y++;
                }
                if (result.Count == n * m)
                    return result;
                y--;x--;

                //right to left moving:
                while (x >= j)
                {
                    result.Add(matrix[y][x]);
                    x--;
                }
                if (result.Count == n * m)
                    return result;
                x++;y--;

                //down to up moving:
                while (y > j)
                {
                    result.Add(matrix[y][x]);
                    y--;
                }
                if (result.Count == n * m)
                    return result;
                y++;x++;
                i++;
                j++;                
            }
    }
```

Comment: Two things:  First, the question was specifically tagged `Javascript`.  That doesn't preclude you from providing an answer in another language, but you probably need to justify doing so by demonstrating an interesting algorithm or some such.  Second, code-only answers are rarely welcome.  Please, when answering, add some description more detailed than "we use loops for each moving directions".