# Snake nail (issue with recursion)

Tags: javascript, recursion, matrix

I try to create the function, that takes n×n matrix (array of arrays) returns one array arter traverse in a clockwise snailshell pattern.

For more information: https://www.codewars.com/kata/521c2db8ddc89b9b7a0000c1

But my code is ok only for 3x3 matrix. If it is bigger there is the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Could you pls help me to understand my mistake

My code:

```
function snail (array) {
  let result = []
  
  function resultFilling(arrayForResult) {
    if (arrayForResult[0].length === 1) {
      result.push(arrayForResult[0][0])
      return
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayForResult.length - 1; i++) {
      result.push(arrayForResult[0][i])
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayForResult.length - 1; i++) {
      result.push(arrayForResult[i][arrayForResult.length - 1])
    }
    for (let i = arrayForResult.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      result.push(arrayForResult[arrayForResult.length - 1][i])
    }
    for (let i = arrayForResult.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      result.push(arrayForResult[i][0])
    }
    
    let newArr = array.reduce((accum, item, index) => {
      if (index > 0 && index < array.length - 1) {
        accum.push(item.splice(1, item.length - 2))
      }
      return accum
    }, [])
    
    if (newArr.length > 0) resultFilling(newArr)
  }
  
  resultFilling(array)

  return result
}
```

Comment: Your best bet may be to write the code non-recursively.

Comment: Yes, i know, that it can be resolved by using "while", but I tried to optimize my code and decided to use recursion. And now I can't really understand why it's not working

Comment: It's not working because you've blown the stack.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57946428, with at least one answer doing this recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to see what's wrong is to add

```js
    console .log (arrayForResult)
```

at the beginning of `resultFilling`.  When you then try with this input:

```js
const arr4x4 = [
  [1,   2,  3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10,  9,  8, 7]
]
```

you will get this in the console:

```js
[[1,2,3,4],[12,13,14,5],[11,16,15,6],[10,9,8,7]]
[[13,14],[16,15]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
[[],[]]
//...
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Which should point us to the problem.  A quick fix would be to replace

```js
    if (newArr.length > 0) resultFilling(newArr)
```

with

```js
    if (newArr.length > 0 && newArr[0].length > 0) resultFilling(newArr)
```

Now you will get this in the console:

```js
[[1,2,3,4],[12,13,14,5],[11,16,15,6],[10,9,8,7]]
[[13,14],[16,15]]
```

and get this return value:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

But if you're interested in an entirely different approach, you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57949870) to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57946428) by expanding this snippet:

```js
const reverse = a => 
  [...a] .reverse ();

const transpose = m => 
  m [0] .map ((c, i) => m .map (r => r [i]))

const rotate = m => 
  reverse (transpose (m))

const spiral = m => m .length < 2
  ? [... m [0]]
  : [... m [0], ... spiral (rotate (m .slice (1))) ] 


console .log (spiral ([
  [1,   2,  3, 4],
  [12, 13, 14, 5],
  [11, 16, 15, 6],
  [10,  9,  8, 7]
]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```